# Entity Framework Defining Query + IsNull + Left Join = Way Too Slow

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, left-join, isnull

I have this SQL statement

```
select st.Column1, isnull(sot.SomeColumn, 0) as SomeColumn 
from SomeTable st 
left join SomeOtherTable sot
```

inside a `<DefiningQuery>` tag inside my Entity Framework (4.0) .edmx file and I'm running into a serious performance issue. Running the SQL as it's written is fast, but EF wraps the SQL during runtime to inject parameters, which slows it down tremendously.

I can take away the isnull, and it's just as fast in the wrapped EF SQL as it is natively, but I need the isnull to ensure `SomeColumn` has a value.

Are there any alternatives to isnull that I could use here that would play nicely with EF?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove any use of `isnull` altogether from my SQL and instead include a `SELECT NEWID() AS ID` (needed this to be SQL 2000+ compatible) with all of these queries. Once I set this `ID` as my single `<EntityKey>`, I could allow set any of the left join properties as `isnullable=true` and I no longer had to deal with the EF slowdown.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In the property's properties in the EF designer there should be a default value property, I'm not sure if that will fit your needs though. As an alternative, all of the entities generated out of you EF model are partials. I would add another property that wraps the SomeColumn property (without the isnull) to provide a default value. Given that SomeColumn will likely be mapped as a nullable int, you can define the new property like this:

```
public SomeColumnWithDefaultValue {
    get { return this.SomeColumn ?? 0; }
    set { this.SomeColumn = value; }
}
```

You would write your queries against SomeColumn and then use SomeColumnWithDefaultValue where you needed to ensure that it was not null.

Comment: I have tried the DefaultValue and that didn't seem to work for me, but it's not a bad idea, the partial property...let me see how it goes. Thanks for the idea...

Comment: Yeah, the partial can be a bit of a pain since it can't be queried against. Have you considered replacing the query with a view?

Comment: The db is an old, crusty thing with weird rules about views...so I don't have that option, unfortunately...it's stupid, I know :)